# How to graph two sets of data with lines and two *different* point symbols with *distinguishable* data point symbols in legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to plot a graph of two sets of data with *different* point symbols *and* connecting lines with different colors using the `R` package `ggplot2`, but for the life of me, I have not been able to get the *legend* correctly distinguish between the two curves by showing the associated data point symbol for each curve.

I can get the legend to show different line *colors*.  But I have not been able to make the legend to show different data point *symbols* for each set of data.

The following code:

```
df <- data.frame( thrd_cnt=c(1,2,4,8,16),
                 runtime4=c(53,38,31,41,54),
                 runtime8=c(54,35,31,35,44))

library("ggplot2")

print(
    ggplot(data = df, aes(df$thrd_cnt, y=df$runtime, color=)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=df$runtime4, color = "4 cores")) +
    geom_point(aes(y=df$runtime4, color = "4 cores"), fill = "white",
               size = 3, shape = 21) +
    geom_line(aes(y=df$runtime8, color = "8 cores")) +
    geom_point(aes(y=df$runtime8, color = "8 cores"), fill = "white",
               size = 3, shape = 23) +
    xlab("Number of Threads") +
    ylab(substitute(paste("Execution Time, ", italic(milisec)))) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,4,8,16)) +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.3, 0.8)) +
    labs(color="# cores")
)

## save a pdf and a png
ggsave("runtime.pdf", width=5, height=3.5)
ggsave("runtime.png", width=5, height=3.5)
```

outputs this graph:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptqZm.png)

But the data point symbols in the legend are *not* distinguishable.  The legend shows the same symbol for both graphs (which is formed of both data point symbols on top of each other).

One possible solution is to define the number of threads as a `factor`, then I might be able to get the data point symbols on the legend right, but still I don't know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, you need to `gather` the data into a long format so you can map the `cores` variable to colour and shape. To keep the same choices of shape and fill as in your original plot, use `scale_shape_manual` to set the shape corresponding to each level of `cores`. Note that you need to set the name for both the `colour` and `shape` legends in `labs()` to ensure they coincide and don't produce two legends. I also used `mutate` so that the levels of `cores` don't confusingly include the word `runtime`.

```r
df <- data.frame( thrd_cnt=c(1,2,4,8,16),
                  runtime4=c(53,38,31,41,54),
                  runtime8=c(54,35,31,35,44))
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(
  data = df %>%
    gather(cores, runtime, runtime4, runtime8) %>%
    mutate(cores = str_c(str_extract(cores, "\\d"), " cores")),
  mapping = aes(x = thrd_cnt, y = runtime, colour = cores)
  ) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape = cores), size = 3, fill = "white") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("4 cores" = 21, "8 cores" = 23)) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.3, 0.8)) +
  labs(
    x = "Number of Threads",
    y = "Execution Time (millisec)",
    colour = "# cores",
    shape = "# cores"
  )
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you for maintaining the original graph format!

Answer (score 0):

after gathering into a "long" formatted data frame, you pass colour and shape (pch) to the aesthetics arguments:

```
library(tidyverse)
    df <- data.frame( thrd_cnt=c(1,2,4,8,16),
                      runtime4=c(53,38,31,41,54),
                      runtime8=c(54,35,31,35,44))

    df %>% gather(key=run, value=time, -thrd_cnt) %>%
      ggplot(aes(thrd_cnt, time, pch=run, colour=run)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

(Notice how brief the code is, compared to the original post)

[image]

Comment: The code is brief because it doesn't keep any of the formatting choices, such as symbol size, symbol shape, legend levels, legend position, and axis numbers.

Answer (score 0):

or `shape` is fine too, and if you're doing more stuff with df, might make sense to convert and keep it in long, 'tidy' format.

```
   library("ggplot2")
   df <- data.frame( thrd_cnt=c(1,2,4,8,16),
              runtime4=c(53,38,31,41,54),
              runtime8=c(54,35,31,35,44))

   df <- df %>% gather("runtime", "millisec", 2:3)

   ggplot(data = df, aes(x = thrd_cnt, y = millisec, color = runtime, shape = 
   runtime)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Comment: Works only if `ggplot2` is replaced with `tidyverse`.  Thanks!